# Use TestNG dataProvider with dependsOnGroups to set order of execution

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have several test cases that depend on each other. The order of execution can be defined in TestNG using [groups](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-gc0bb558-111/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#groups--) and [dependsOnGroups](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-gc0bb558-111/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnGroups--) in the `@Test` annotation:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test(groups = { "group1" })
    public void testCase1() {
    }

    @Test(groups = {"group2"}, dependsOnGroups = { "group1" })
    public void testCase2() {
    }

    @Test(groups = {"group2"}, dependsOnGroups = { "group1" })
    public void testCase() {
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group3" }, dependsOnGroups = { "group2" })
    public void testCase4() {
    }
}
```

But I want it dynamically with only one `@Test` method and a `@DataProvider` that gives me the group and the dependencies.

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases", groups = {testCase[1]}, dependsOnGroups  = {testCase[2]})
    public void executeTest(TestCase testCase) throws Exception {
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] getTestCases() {
        Object[][] testdata = new Object[...][...];
        // Fields: test name, group, depends on, test data 
        testdata[0] = {"TC#1", "group1", "",       "foo data"};
        testdata[1] = {"TC#2", "group2", "group1", "bar data"};
        testdata[2] = {"TC#3", "group2", "group1", "bzz data"};
        testdata[3] = {"TC#4", "group3", "group2", "frr data"};
        return testdata;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this approach does not work, as testCase[1] cannot be accessed from the `@Test(..., groups = {testCase[1]}, ...)` annotation.

Is there another approach to get data-provider driven tests into a fixed order?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work , do you mean that you are not able to get data from  `@Dataprovider` in the above code or you want to not enter data in `@Dataprovider`  but want it some other way ?

Comment: @user1207289 I clarified what I want to achieve: get data-driven test cases into a fixed order.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and edit, I  think you would like to get data into all your methods and run them in the order they appear in your class.

You can use below approach and `testng.xml` with `preserve-order="true"` to get your data driven test to run. Note that you may have to remove `groups` and  `dependsOnGroups` as below to run this.

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")     
    public void testCase1(Object[][] obj) {
        //access obj to get data
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testCase2(Object[][] obj1) {
    //access obj1 to get data
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testCase(Object[][] obj2) {
     //access obj2 to get data

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testCase4(Object[][] obj3) {
         //access obj3 to get data
    }
}
```

here is your `testng.xml` that should run it in the order they appear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="yourSuiteName" >

    <test name="FirstScenario_1" preserve-order="true">

        <classes>  
         <class name="yourPackage.MyTest" >
               <methods> 
                  <include name="testCase1" />
                  <include name="testCase2" /> 
                  <include name="testCase" />
                  <include name="testCase4" />
               </methods> 
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do not want to create a test method for every test case as they are dynamically created (e.g. read from spreadsheet or database table) => each data is one test case. Maybe I need another approach for this, but for now the dataProvider is working very well except for I cannot set up the order the test cases are executed in.

Comment: @arnep The above xml will set the order up